# Two dimensional array in assembly code

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

How can I convert this to mips assembly code

```
M[][]= {{1, 2, 3, 4},{5, 6, 7, 8},{9, 10, 11, 12},{13, 14, 15, 16}}
```

should I break this array into two or what?
like this?

```
M1: .byte 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
M2: .byte 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
```

Comment: you didn't "break" the array, it's still one sequence of bytes. the object created doesn't care for how many labels you had, and how many lines code you used to create it. the question is how to access these bytes, esp how to convert array access m[x][y] to the correct byte position (M1+4+y+x), and how to care for alignment

Answer (score 1):

No, it's single continuous `M` array of 16 byte values (1-16). The "two MxN dimensions" are faked by the index mapping function *fmap(n, m) = n*M + m*, and then address of element(n, m) is `M + fmap(m, n)`.

I.e. to fetch M[2, 3] from 4x4 array you calculate offset of element as 2*4 + 3 = 11 (if indices are going from 0 of course, as every decent low level programming language does, eat this pascal!), so this would be element with value 12 (last one in third group).

The computer memory is only "one-dimensional", so any more complex structure has to be mapped to it by the code.